# Word2Vec and Gensim parameters equivalence

Tags: python, nlp, neural-network, gensim, word2vec

Gensim is an optimized python port of Word2Vec (see http://radimrehurek.com/2013/09/deep-learning-with-word2vec-and-gensim/)

I am currently using these vectors: http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/composes/semantic-vectors.html

I am going to rerun the model training with gensim because there was some noisy tokens in their models. So i would like to find out what are some equivalent parameters for `word2vec` in `gensim`

And the parameters they used from `word2vec` are:

- 2-word context window, PMI weighting, no compression, 300K dimensions

What is the gensim equivalence when i train a Word2Vec model?

Is it:

```
>>> model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=300000, window=2, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

**Is there a PMI weight option in gensim?**

**What is the default min_count used in word2vec?**

There's another set of parameters from word2vec as such:

- 5-word context window, 10 negative samples, subsampling, 400 dimensions.

**Is there a negative samples parameter in gensim?**

**What is the parameter equivalence of subsampling in gensim?**

Comment: please explain why is the question too broad? In any sense, it's very specific to API usage and finding out whether there are hidden parameters that are not documented and parameters equivalence between a python port of the word2vec tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The paper you link to compares word embeddings from a number of schemes, including Continuous Bag of Words (CBOW). CBOW is one of the models implemented in Gensim's "word2vec" model. The paper also discusses word embeddings obtained from Singular Value Decomposition with various weighting schemes, some involving PMI. There is no equivalence between SVD and word2vec, but if you want to do an SVD in gensim, it's called "LSA" or "Latent Semantic Analysis" when done in natural language processing.
2. The `min_count` parameter is set to 5 by default, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py).
3. Negative Sampling and Hierarchical Softmax are two approximate inference methods for estimating a probability distribution over a discrete space (used when a normal softmax is too computationally expensive). Gensim's `word2vec` implements both. It uses hierarchical softmax by default, but you can use negative sampling by setting the hyperparameter `negative` to be greater than zero. This is documented in comments in gensim's code [here](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py) as well.